# Matlab TCP/IP Server Socket Multiple Connections

Tags: matlab, sockets, tcp

I understand how to get a one-to-one client-server connection setup in MATLAB using the information contained here:

[http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/using-tcpip-server-sockets.html][1]

However, it doesn't deal with allowing the server to listen for and accept multiple client connections (on the same port).  Is this possible using purely native MATLAB?  Or do I need to use some form of Java back-end for the socket (for example).

My other option is to create a server that accepts connections on multiple ports (one for each client), but I would rather avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a bit late. Your question is not matlab specific. Usually the client contacts the server on a well known port, like what you are saying, then the server tells the client what port they should use that will be just for that specific client. Then the client switches to that port.